# Identify a wire protruding my plug

Tags: identification

I have a simple question, can you identify what this is on my plug and what it does? I'm kinda curious as to why it is there and I have never seen anything like it before.

[image: Picture of the plug for my monitor]

Comment: optional ground for shielded AC wire.

Answer (score 1):

That wire is for an additional connection to earth ground. The plug itself has no third prong for an earth connection. The manual of the device with this plug should contain some information about this wire and its use.

Comment: This type of plug is typical in Japan. If the device was made in that region, the manual may not bother mentioning it -- it's common enough there that most people would be expected to recognize it.